# Dictation single button shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, voice-dictation

So to start off I'm ridiculously disabled. Can only use one hand (among many other things). Have started experimenting with the dictation accessibility functionality. So far its mostly in the form of using keyboard shortcuts.

Have been creating my own shortcuts for applications that allow your own shortcut config files. For example the IINA media player. This has worked wonderfully.

However, there are numerous applications, well, most of them, that don't allow this. They use single buttons such as D or ESCAPE which it seems you cannot create voice commands for. So, I was wondering, does anyone know of a workaround for this? Or perhaps an alternate voice recognition app (preferably not in the price range of Dragon Speech)?

I am relatively experienced with the command line if that helps open up some options.

Thank-you!